# Custom Suggestions in Search Widget (Android ICS)

Tags: android, search, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, android-actionbar

I have an action bar with a search widget in my ICS app. I want that the user can search some stuff which came with the app. Therefore I want to use the search widget, displaying a result list which updates itselfs when the user typ in a new char (same functionality like the Play Store). I have implemented `SearchView.OnQueryTextListener` in my activity and implement the two methods `onQueryTextChange(String newText)` and `onQueryTextSubmit(String query)`. In `onQueryTextChange` I call my service, that returns the values for the typed suggestion. But I have no plan, how to display a suggestion list. I read the articles on [developer.android.com](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/search/adding-custom-suggestions.html), but as far as I understand it is mainly for the old search implementation (< Honeycomb). In the Search Widget API Examples the suggestions are apps, installed on the system, served by `SearchManager`. I havn't found a tutorial or example which covers this topic (custom suggestions in search widget), does anybody know something like this?

```
@Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.search_menu, menu);
       
        
        
        SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
        
        SearchView searchView = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.menu_search).getActionView();    
        
        
        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(this);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

@Override
    public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Query = " + newText);
        
      if(newText.length() > 0){
          //my suggestion service, returning an arraylist!
      }
        
        return false;
    }
```

I read, that I need a `ContentProvider` extend from `SearchRecentSuggestionsProvider`, but I don't know how I handle and create this provider. I have a `searchable.xml` which refers as `searchSuggestAuthority` to my blank content provider. In the AnroidManifest I added a Search Intent to the MainActivity, add the meta-data and added my provider. But I don't know how to get my values to the Content Provider and display these as suggestions.

```
public class SuggentionsProvider extends SearchRecentSuggestionsProvider {
    public final static String AUTHORITY = "com.sap.hui.helper.SuggentionsProvider";
    public final static int MODE = DATABASE_MODE_QUERIES;
    
    public SuggentionsProvider(){
        setupSuggestions(AUTHORITY, MODE);
    }
}
```

BR,

mybecks

Comment: did u find the solution? if yes, please share me

Answer (score 4):

I believe these are what you need.

The tutorial:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/search/adding-custom-suggestions.html

The example:

http://developer.android.com/tools/samples/index.html

Comment: It seems google has updated the whole developer section, since the I/O. So I will try to get into it again. :)

Comment: The first link describes it in detail.